# Use predicate to get DateTime parameter ordered in descending order

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-cosmosdb, linqkit

I'm trying to use the predicate builder to get the LastVerifiedDate ordered in descending order by using the `PredicateBuilder` in `LinqKit` So far It didn't work out. Here's what I have tried so far:

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.New<Item>();
predicate.And(f => OrderByDescending(f.LastVerfiedDate)); // Not working code
```

Im okay to add to Cosmos Query aswell like below:

```
var response = _client.CreateDocumentQuery<T>(_tools.GetCollectionUri<T>(),
                 new FeedOptions
                 {
                 PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(partitionKey), MaxItemCount = requestCommand.PageSize,
                 RequestContinuation = requestCommand.Token
                 })

var docQuery = response.Where(predicate).OrderByDescending(f.LastVerfiedDate); // OrderByDescending not available
```

**Question:**

**Can this be achievable using CreateDocumentQuery?
Basically I need to fetch data in descending order based on `LastVerifiedDate` attribute.  If so can someone provide code sample which I can try out?**

Comment: Ordering is not a predicate here so rather no you can't but you should be able too simple append it to the query. `query.Where(predicate).OrderByDescending(f.LastVerfiedDate)`.

Comment: There is no `query.where(predicate).OrderByDescending() ` available

Comment: That was an example you need to adapt to your code.

Comment: `OrderByDescending(f.LastVerfiedDate)` is invalid. The correct expression is `OrderByDescending(f=>f.LastVerfiedDate)` . The method expects an expression that returns a sort key. It's not a predicate, ie an expression returning True/False

Comment: What's the actual problem anyway? The Cosmos code contains a normal LINQ query with a typo. LinqKit isn't used anywhere. If `T` is constrained by a type constraint to implement a type or interface with a `LastVerifiedDate` property, there's no need for a dynamic query

Comment: I need to query data by sorting on attribute `LastVerifiedDate ` which is DateTime in descending order @PanagiotisKanavos.

Comment: You do that with `OrderByDescending(f=>f.LastVerfiedDate)`. Not with `OrderByDescending(f.LastVerfiedDate)`. There's no `OrderByDescending(DateTime)` or `OrderByDescending<T>(T)`. The definition is [OrderByDescending(...,Expression<Func<TSource,TKey>> keySelector)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.orderbydescending?view=net-7.0#system-linq-queryable-orderbydescending-2(system-linq-iqueryable((-0))-system-linq-expressions-expression((system-func((-0-1))))))

Comment: To your updated question - yes it can, if you use the correct method. `response.Where(predicate).OrderByDescending(f=>f.LastVerfiedDate);`. If you want to make your method generic on T, there should be a type constraint like `where T:IHasLastVerifiedDate`, eg `IEnumerable<T> GetDocsByDate<T>(...) where T:IHasLastVerifiedDate { ...}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was basically able to achieve ordering data based on Expression via the below code. Posting it here for anyones reference.

My use case was to order the data based on `DateTime` parameter called `LastVerifiedDate` which I have from data fetched CreateDocumentQuery. I was able to achieve like below :

```
    public async Task<PagedResults<TResult>> GetPagedAsync<TResult>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, Expression<Func<T, DateTime>> orderedByDateAscending,
        PagedCommand<T> requestCommand, string partitionKey = null)
    {
        var response = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(partitionKey)
            ? _client
                .CreateDocumentQuery<T>(_tools.GetCollectionUri<T>(),
                    new FeedOptions
                        {MaxItemCount = requestCommand.PageSize, RequestContinuation = requestCommand.Token})
            : _client
                .CreateDocumentQuery<T>(_tools.GetCollectionUri<T>(),
                    new FeedOptions
                    {
                        PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(partitionKey), MaxItemCount = requestCommand.PageSize,
                        RequestContinuation = requestCommand.Token
                    });
        var docQuery = response.Where(predicate).OrderBy(orderedByDateAscending); // Pass it like this to OrderBy method
        var total = requestCommand.TotalRecords;
        if (requestCommand.Token == null && !requestCommand.HasMore)
        {
            total = docQuery.Count();
        }

        var query = docQuery.AsDocumentQuery();
        var list = await query.ExecuteNextAsync<TResult>();
        var pagedResult = new PagedResults<TResult>(requestCommand.PageSize, total, list.ResponseContinuation,
            query.HasMoreResults, requestCommand.PageIndex + 1, list.ToList());

        return pagedResult;
    }
```

Invoking the above method like below :

```
Expression<Func<StartPoints, DateTime>> orderByExpression = e=>e.LastVerfiedDate;    
    var results = await _myQueryRepository.GetPagedAsync<ItemDto>(predicate, orderByExpression, request);
```